# TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface issue

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, byte

import csv
    import operator

```
writenames = "col1, Name, col2, col3, col4".split(",")
reader = csv.DictReader(open("Test.csv", "rb"))
writer = csv.DictWriter(open("Test1.csv", "wb"), \
    fieldnames=writenames)
reorderfunct = lambda r: dict([(col, r[col]) for col in writenames])
writer.writeheader()
for row in reader:
    writer.writerow(reorderfunct(row)
```

outputs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\evan.keeler\My Documents\LiClipse Workspace\Test
Test\ColumnSwitch.py", line 10, in <module>
     writer.writeheader()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\csv.py", line 142, in writeheader
    self.writerow(header)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\csv.py", line 153, in writerow
    return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

I'm not sure what the issues is here?  I know that you must cast a string as bytes but I'm not sure how to do that with this particular example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python3 csv files need to be opened in text mode, not binary, and they need to be opened with newline=''.

```
reader = csv.DictReader(open("Test.csv", "r", newline=''))
writer = csv.DictWriter(open("Test1.csv", "w", newline=''), fieldnames=writenames)
```

This is unfortuantly only mentioned in the [csv.reader and csv.writer docs:](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/csv.html#csv.reader)

> If csvfile is a file object, it should be opened with newline=''

Though it is also required by the DictReader and DictWriter.

Opening csv files in binary mode is only needed in python2.

Answer (score 0):

You should open files in text mode, not binary mode.

```
reader = csv.DictReader(open("Test.csv", "r"))
writer = csv.DictWriter(open("Test1.csv", "w"), fieldnames=writenames)
```

See [DictReader documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader).

Comment: Doing that avoids the error, but adds a newline after each row. `newline=''` is the way.